# Do we tell the object to do something or do we do something (on/with/to/etc.) the object?

Tags: domain-driven-design, semantics

Take the (unprecedented and groundbreaking) example of the calculator:

```
public class Calculator
{
    public double Add(double augend, double addend) 
    {
        return augend + addend;
    }
}
```

When I write `calculator.Add(val1, val2)` which of the following am I doing?

- Telling the calculator to add the inputs
- Adding the inputs with the calculator

(One could also ask: "Is it a method *of* the object or is it a method *on* the object?")

Other examples: do we tell the repository to add the entity or do we add the entity to the repository? Do we tell the message service to deliver a message or do we send a message through the message service? Do we tell the can of paint to mix itself or do we mix the can of paint?

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'").** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It's not necessary either of your two choices. Maybe it is a message to the object.

Comment: @gnat "Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals and students in software development and related fields who are interested in getting expert answers on **conceptual questions about software development.**"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about vocabulary.

Comment: Are questions about "tell, don't ask" off-topic as well? Do I have to use an established acronym or phrase or cute word like "Scrum" to have a valid question?

Comment: Most programming languages are actually meta-languages. You use them to develop the business language that you will use to solve your problem. That means it is up to you to put in the meaning most appropriate for your problem domain. If it makes more sense to mix the paint then mix the paint, but if your problem requires the paint to mix itself then define the paint to mix itself. You get to decide what is most appropriate for your current situation, and then do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it a method of the object or is it a method on the object?

It is a method of the *class.*

You create instances of classes to encapsulate *state,* not *code.*  All of the code in that method is the same code across all of the objects; only the state (private variables) varies between objects.

Calling methods is a form of *message passing.*  You send a message to an object by calling a method.  The method can send back a message of its own by returning some value. The method may also cause side effects by altering the state of the object, writing to a log, etc.

> Do we tell the can of paint to mix or do we mix the can of paint?

If you call

```
canOfPaint.Mix();
```

You are telling the can of paint to mix.

If you call

```
Mix(canOfPaint)
```

You are mixing the can of paint.

Comment: I have been thinking like that for as long as I have been developing but I want to know *why.* Why think of methods as actions that objects can do rather than actions that we can do with objects? Or is there room for both, as @Prog touches on?

Comment: Because generally you want your behavior and your state to be *encapsulated in the same place,* generally within the class definition.  That's one of the primary motivators of OOP.

Comment: Right, and I wouldn't want to have everything be a bag of public getter/setters with static helper libraries. Encapsulation is important and I'm not advocating against it. I'm just trying to figure out, given an instance of a class with some logic encapsulated in its methods, *how am I to best describe and conceptualize the usage of those methods*?

Comment: I want to personally thank you for your discussion as well. I know the matter might be trivial to a lot of people but I never would have expected the negativity and dismissal that I received from the beginning.

Comment: It mystifies some of us that you are wrestling with something that seems so self-evident.  Programming languages are called "languages" for a reason; they conceptualize things just like "real" languages do.  So when you say `Mix(canOfPaint)`, you're mixing a can of paint, just like the code says.  When you say `canOfPaint.Mix()`, you're telling the can of paint to mix itself.  Just like the code says.  There are valid use cases for both approaches.

Comment: I suspect that there is something fundamental about OOP that you don't quite understand yet, and this whole bit about cans of paint is a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Comment: The existence of principles such as domain driven design and "Tell, don't ask" demonstrate the importance of semantics in software development. It's not a red herring, it's not a lack of understanding SOLID or anything like that, it's just my hesitance to settle on "telling a can of paint to mix itself" when I think would admit myself to a psych ward if I ever saw a can of paint mix itself after someone told it to.

Comment: @tuespetre: Then you're using the wrong metaphor. How about this one: when you turn the key to start a car, does the car know what to do, or do you have to teach it every time?  Do you put the car into a car-starting machine, or does it already possess the means to start itself?  Remember, this isn't the real world; it's a virtual one.  If you want the can of paint to mix itself, you can certainly do that in a virtual world.

Comment: It's settled then. If the object does something, use an instance method. If you do something to/with/etc. the object, use a static method (in the same class if needing access to internals.)

Comment: It's a little more nuanced than that, but yes, that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's a matter of the context in the system, and sometimes depends on the conceptual role of the component in the system.

For example in a game, a character might have a method `attack()`. Is it meant to allow other characters to attack this character? Or is it a method used to tell the character to attack? Totally depends on your system.

Comment: Hopefully the code is written clearly enough that the context is apparent.

Comment: You could even take it to the point of 'making an attack with the knight' by having the 'attack' method produce an attack object that is evaluated elsewhere. Maybe it's all just preference -- but then some would say that "tell, don't ask" is not a preference but a best practice. I'm just trying to make it all click. Thank you for not brushing me aside.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it doesn't matter.

If you're telling a `Calculator` object to add, your code looks like this:

```
class Calculator {
  public Double add(Double a, Double b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

If you're adding two number *with* a `Calculator`, it looks like this:

```
class Calculator {
  public Double add(Double a, Double b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

The implementation is the same. And I suspect your code will be the same in most cases regardless of which preposition you use to describe it. In most cases, your object is both the subject and direct object of the verb. In cases where it *won't* be the same, you should try to clarify the method name or include adequate documentation to indicate what role the object plays in the action.

Comment: Well... *sort of.*  In a curly-brace language with classes, your second example would be a `static` method in a `static` class.  While this seems like an inconsequential distinction, the first example does require you to instantiate an object, while the second one (if it is made `static`) does not.  The distinction between `to` and `with` matters less than whether or not you plan to hold state (such as a total).

Comment: I think this is the best answer I can hope for. I have to break myself of interpreting ```object.Method()``` as always having 'object' as the subject. ```Assert.AreEqual(true, (code.IsLike(english) && !code.Equals(english)));```

Comment: @tuespetre: True enough.  A method can act on the object you call it on, but it can also act on some other object instead, if you pass it into the method's parameter(s).

Comment: Hmmm, I think your point is sinking in, @RobertHarvey. Since static methods can access the internals of instances of the same class, perhaps I could reserve instance methods for things that the instance *does* and use static methods for things you do *with*.